# Module error with Werkzeug 0.7

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, flask, werkzeug

I try to learn flask with some basic examplse, but even with the example on the original flask website, i get an error coming from Werkzeug http.py.

Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Here is the error: https://pastebin.com/7N1TP0zm

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\http.py", line 26, in <module>
    from urllib.request import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "C:\Users\Adrien\Desktop\http.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adrien\Desktop\http.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
    __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\exceptions.py", line 71, in <module>
    from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 26, in <module>
    from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES, \
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\http.py", line 29, in <module>
    from urllib2 import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'
```

additional informations:

- i'm on windows 7 64 bit
- i use python 3.6 64 bit
- the Werkzeug version seems to be 0.12.2

I tried unistalling and installing python multiple times, but it don't help.
Thanks in advance for you help.

EDIT:
when in try to install urllib2 i get this error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requierement urllib2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for urllib2
```

Comment: Did you install flask correctly.? reinstall and see the error. TO solve this specific error do pip install urllib2

Comment: i tried reinstalling flask multiple times, but don't help. I have an error hen trying to install urllib2 with pip.

Comment: Could you solve it in any way? Got the same problem